# SFML 3D MouseLook

Tags: c#, opengl, mouse, sfml

Edit2:
I figured out most of the problem, but there is one annoyance that I have. When the cursor reaches the edge of the screen and is pulled to the other side, the camera jerks, which won't work. Can someone see how that could be stopped?

```
    bool attention = true;
    Vector2 p, mousePos;
    private float MOUSE_SENSITIVITY = 4.0f;

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseMoveEventArgs e)
    {
        float DeltX = 0, DeltY = 0;
        int border = 2;
        Console.WriteLine(attention + "");

        if (attention == true)
        {
            p.X = e.X;
            p.Y = e.Y;

            DeltX = (float)(mousePos.X - e.X) / MOUSE_SENSITIVITY;
            DeltY = (float)(mousePos.Y - e.Y) / MOUSE_SENSITIVITY;
        }
        else
        {
            mousePos = p;
        }

        attention = true;

        if (e.X > App.Width - border)
        {
            attention = false;
            App.SetCursorPosition((uint)border, (uint)e.Y);
            DeltX = 0;
            DeltY = 0;

        }
        else if (e.X < border)
        {
            attention = false;
            App.SetCursorPosition((uint)(App.Width - border), (uint)e.Y);
            DeltX = 0;
            DeltY = 0;

        }

        if (e.Y > App.Height - border)
        {
            attention = false;
            App.SetCursorPosition((uint)e.X, (uint)border);
            DeltX = 0;
            DeltY = 0;

        }
        else if (e.Y < border)
        {
            attention = false;
            App.SetCursorPosition((uint)e.X, (uint)(App.Height - border));
            DeltX = 0;
            DeltY = 0;

        }



        Cam.RotateY(DeltX);
        Cam.RotateX(DeltY);


        mousePos = p;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you set the mouse position to the center of the window each frame. Previously you read to mouse position and subtract the center of the window. This way you can easily get the mouse movement each frame without having to worry about window borders.

```
Vector2i center(window->getSize().x / 2, window->getSize().y / 2);
Vector2i delta = Mouse::getPosition(*window) - center;
Mouse::setPosition(center, *window);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still getting up to speed myself, so please take this with a grain of salt. (I'm trying!)

I think your mouse movement is measured in pixels & this translates to complete revolutions of the camera. By dividing by 0.4, (MOUSE_MOVEMENT,) you're affecting some multiple of "0.4 complete revolutions", (e.g. 152 pixels / .04 = 380 revolutions, leaving you facing the same direction as you started in.)

Try dividing by 256 instead of 0.4 & see if that works better.

Comment: That is a good idea, although I've already figured it out, I just used a wrap-around bit of code, so when the mouse gets close to the edge it gets set back to the other side, and it seems to work pretty well.

Comment: I realized after posting this that I was thinking of the way an old engine (from the 90's) worked. I forgot OpenGL uses degrees for it's rotations.

Comment: There must be a way to poll the mouse at a lower level than screen coordinates, wouldn't you think? If so, couldn't you then check mouse *movement*, regardless of whether or not the cursor is at the edge of the screen?

Comment: I fixed it, I just checked if the jump was greater than 150 or 200 pixels it ignored it, so when it jumps from one side of the screen to the other it ignores it.